# How many characters can a cell in .CSV file hold?

Tags: csv, export-to-csv

i am trying to extract data from a table in which one of the column has more than 2000+ characters. Can i have this extracted to .csv file with out any data loss

Comment: since there is no official standard for csv-files and RFC 4180 does not specify any length-limits - it depends on the export-capabilities of the software you use.

Comment: @piet.t the lack of an offical standard makes this a good question to ask. I've done months of research into what can/can't be done reliably in a CSV file and am happy to pass it on here.

Answer (score 2):

As far as csv is concerned, there is no limit on the size of the cells/fields (a field could even hold another csv file, or a full html page, if properly escaped).

But some software to view the csv data might have trouble with too large fields.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official CSV format and it's often difficult or even impossible to make a CSV file that imports perfectly for all users.

However, for text cells Microsoft Excel can hold up to 32,767 characters in a cell, except for headers and footers, which are limited to 255 characters.

I would expect other programs to have similar (or higher) limits.